# TypeError HTMLSpanElement has no method 'html'

Tags: jquery

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSpanElement> has no method 'html'
```

When I am running this method

```
$("input[name=advancedSettings]").change(function() {
  $('span[id^="sFile"]').each(function() {
    this.html('Hey');
  });
});
```

And span should of course have a method called text and html, and I have tested with both

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should run `.html()` on a jquery object:

```
$(this).html('Hey');
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot the dollar sign and the parentes, and I have tried so many other things